"Center" of a set of binary strings
For a finite set $A$ in a metric space define its diameter ${\rm diam} (A)$ as the maximal distance between two points in $A$ and radius $r(A)$ as the minimal radius of a ball containing $A$. Obviously, $r(A)\leqslant {\rm diam} (A)$. My question concerns a situation when this inequality (possibly) may be improved.
Consider the Hamming cube $\{0,1\}^{4n}$. If $A\subset \{0, 1\}^{4n}$ satisfies $|A|\leqslant 2n+1$ and ${\rm diam} (A)\leqslant 2n$, does it follow that $r(A) \leqslant 2n-1$?
In plain language, if we have $2n+1$ binary strings of length $4n$, and the mutual Hamming distances between them are at most $2n$, does there always exist a binary string $s$ such that the distance from $s$ to them all is at most $2n-1$?
I only checked it for $n=1,2$ on my computer.

A first attempt would be to guess $s$ as the majority vote on $A$ , i.e. $s(i) =1$, iff more than half of the $a\in A$ satisfy $a(i)=1$. Do you have an example where this $s$ does not do the job? (Of course this is still far away from a proof).

@HenrikRüping, for the set of strings
$$11110111 \ 00011111\ 00101111 \ 01001111 \ 10001111$$
the majority vote is 00001111
which has distance 5
to the first string, while every other string in the set has distance 4

Perhaps, it is worth it ro take a Hadamard matrix of order, say, 16 and to check all 9-tuples of its rows (multiplied by $\pm1$) to have this property...

I have solved an Integer Linear Program in binary variables, in which I have furtherly forced the mutual Hamming distances to be exactly $2n$ and obtained $1,3,4,6$ as upper bounds for the distances with $s$ for $n=1,2,3,4$. Since imposing the mutual distances to be within $[2n-k,2n]$ gives a bound of $4,3,3,1$ for $n=3$ and $k=1,2,3,4$, and a bound of $3,1$ for $n=2$ and $k=1,2$, then having the mutual distances equal to exactly $2n$ might be the actual worst case (unproven). Note also that the bounds $4,6$ obtained for $n=3,4$ are $\lt 2n-1$. Case $n=5$ still running after an hour.

This is among "Consensus String Problems", although here we don't want to get a specific $s$ from a given input set of strings, but only to know whether it always exists.
